# Change List field after due date

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I have a customer that is working with tests, each test have a confidentiality date. When that date accrues then the its possible to use the test again, the test gets unlocked.

So i am wondering how I can get this functionality, i have a date column and a "Locked" yes or no column. When the date column is equal or later then [Today] then i want to change the "Locked" to "No" ("Locked" column starts on "Yes").
I want this to happen automatically.

What solution should I use, workflows, C#, JavaScript?

I would appreciate a example if its possible.

Answer (score 4):

Couple of options

1. Workflow - Not recommended way

   Here you invoke the workflow on item create or update, then use Pause Activity to pause the workflow till due date. Then Update Current Item and set Locked = No
2. Timer Job - Recommended way

   Here you create a Timer Job that runs daily (say 12 AM). It loop through items that are expired (use CAML query). Then update Locked = No
3. Task Scheduler - Recommended way

   Here you create a PowerShell Script that loop through items that are expired (use CAML query). Then update Locked = No.
      Schedule PowerShell script using Task Scheduler to runs daily (say 12 AM).